# Why do I get PDOException SQLSTATE[42S22] Column not found 1054 Unknown column 'tn.tid' in 'on clause'"?

Tags: 7

```
$rtid = arg(2);

$query = "SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM node
  WHERE (node.nid IN (
    SELECT tn.nid AS nid
    FROM taxonomy_index AS tn
    LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th ON th.tid = tn.tid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th1 ON th.parent = th1.tid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th2 ON th1.parent = th2.tid
    WHERE (tn.tid = :rtid) OR (th1.tid = :rtid) OR (th2.tid = :rtid)
  ))
  AND (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('product'))
  ORDER BY node_created DESC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0";

$result = db_query($query, array(':rtid' => $rtid));
```

After I tried some times with the help of other users' answers, I got lost. This is the code I tried, but it gives me an error ("PDOException SQLSTATE[42S22] Column not found 1054 Unknown column 'tn.tid' in 'on clause'").

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition('n.type', 'product')
  ->condition(
    db_or()
      ->condition('tn.tid',$rtid )
      ->condition('th1.tid',$rtid)
      ->condition('th2.tid',$rtid)
  )
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))     
  ->extend('PagerDefault')       
  ->limit(1);

$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', 'th.tid = tn.tid');
$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th1', 'th.parent = th1.tid');
$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th2', 'th1.parent = th2.tid');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: which table represents tn ?

Comment: FROM taxonomy_index AS tn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is caused by the fact you don't use tn as alias of any database table.

The code I would write is the following one.

```
$tid = arg(2);
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$tn = $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', '%alias.nid = n.nid');
$th = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', "%alias.tid = $tn.tid");
$th1 = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th1', "%alias.tid = $th.parent");
$th2 = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th2', "%alias.tid = $th1.parent");

$query->condition('n.type', 'product')
  ->condition(
    db_or()
      ->condition("$tn.tid", $tid)
      ->condition("$th1.parent", $tid)
      ->condition("$th2.parent", $tid)
  )
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(1);
```

`$query->join()` is really doing an INNER join; if you need to make a LEFT OUTER join, then the code is the following.

```
$tid = arg(2);
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$tn = $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'tn', '%alias.nid = n.nid');
$th = $query->addJoin('LEFT OUTER', 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', "%alias.tid = $tn.tid");
$th1 = $query->addJoin('LEFT OUTER', 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th1', "%alias.tid = $th.parent");
$th2 = $query->addJoin('LEFT OUTER', 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th2', "%alias.tid = $th1.parent");

$query->condition('n.type', 'product')
  ->condition(
    db_or()
      ->condition("$tn.tid", $tid)
      ->condition("$th1.parent", $tid)
      ->condition("$th2.parent", $tid)
  )
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(1);
```

As side notes:

- `$query->join()`, and `$query->addJoin()` returns the alias they used
- In the conditions passed to `$query->join()`, and `$query->addJoin()` %alias is replaced with the table alias the method is using

[SelectQuery::addJoin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddJoin/7) avoids conflicts between aliases using the following code.

```
  $alias_candidate = $alias;
  $count = 2;
  while (!empty($this->tables[$alias_candidate])) {
    $alias_candidate = $alias . '_' . $count++;
  }
  $alias = $alias_candidate;

  if (is_string($condition)) {
    $condition = str_replace('%alias', $alias, $condition);
  }
```

Writing code similar to the one I used, you are sure not to cause any conflict between aliases, and it is useful in the case the code is changed successively, or part of the query is populated from a function.
In this case, the join part could have written as follows, and it could still work correctly.

```
$tn = $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'tn', '%alias.nid = n.nid');
$th = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', "%alias.tid = $tn.tid");
$th1 = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', "%alias.tid = $th.parent");
$th2 = $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', "%alias.tid = $th1.parent");
```

Comment: i put your query code in, but there is no any result output. i print the query.  SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM 
node AS n INNER JOIN taxonomy_index AS ti 
ON ti.nid = n.nid INNER JOIN 
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th ON th.tid = ti.tid INNER JOIN 
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th1 ON th1.tid = th.parent 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th2 ON th2.tid = th1.parent 
WHERE (n.type = product) AND( (ti.tid = 6)
 OR (th1.parent = 6) OR (th2.parent = 6) )  then test term id=6 run in phpmyadmin, shows 1054 - Unknown column 'product' in 'where clause'

Comment: the second ways with term id =4 test show the same result,  1054 - Unknown column 'product' in 'where clause'                               SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM node AS n 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_index AS tn ON tn.nid = n.nid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th 
ON th.tid = tn.tid LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th1 
ON th1.tid = th.parent LEFT OUTER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS th2 ON th2.tid = th1.parent 
WHERE (n.type = product)
 AND( (tn.tid = 4) 
OR (th1.parent = 4) OR (th2.parent = 4) )

Comment: after read you code again and again, i don't know where is the error is?thank you

Comment: The error is simply the fact there isn't any database table using tn as alias in `db_select()`, or in `$query->join()`. The error is telling you "I don't know what table is tn."

Comment: taxonomy_index AS tn, but in your code. $tn = $query->join('taxonomy_index', 'tn', '%alias.nid = n.nid'); this line shows tn as alias to the taxonomy_index

Comment: In the code where you use `db_select()`, you are not using tn as alias of any table, not in `db_select()`, nor in `$query->join()`. My code uses tn as alias, but your code doesn't.

Comment: i delete my code instead of run your code,it gives the above which i told error shows;

Comment: would you mind do i test to your code? many thanks. i put it in a template file. it shows nothing.

Comment: If two pagers are being added in the same page, it is probable they are conflicting with each other.